# How to have powershell automatically take info from a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to have PowerShell execute a script automatically with data from a SQL Server database.

For example:

1. User inputs data on a (internal) website (done/works)
2. PHP takes that info and puts it into a SQL Server database (done/works)
3. PowerShell needs to see that data has been entered and automatically triggers a function (stuck)
4. PowerShell takes the input from SQL Server as a string and executes a script on the server with it (done/works)

So the user input is a target computer on the network. And the script takes it and runs this command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName '$userinput' -ScriptBlock { Get-ComputerInfo }
```

I think it would have to be like:

```
if input(XYZ) exists in table(123) then execute function(ABC).
```

but I don't know how to do that in PowerShell.

I am a front end developer and am a little out of my element with this, but branching out is good!

Comment: Powerhell doesn't "detect" the data has been input, you need to get *something* to trigger the powershell; either SQL Server or PHP. They are the event drivers here.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but SO has rules.  [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This also means you are new ro PowerShell, so, it' sprudent to get ramped up on it first. Youtube is your friend. Serach for 'Beginning PowerShell' and read/practice with  'Powershell in a month of lunches, by Don Jones.'

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to launch this from SQL Server.  While SQL does have scripting functionality called `triggers`, it's all centered around working within the database and you don't want to impede progress by having SQL launch external commands and wait till finished.

Here's how I've done something similar in the past.

1. Add a new column to your table called `Processed` and give it a bit value type which can be used for true/false, with a default value of false.
2. Add a new view to your database called v_UnprocessedEvents or something similar, the view should only return rows where `Processed = false`, so it would look like

`select * from dbo.yourTableName where Processed = false`

3. Write a PowerShell script to `select * from v_UnprocessedEvents` and then do some action on each of them.
4. Within the loop for each record, update the `Processed` value to `True` at the end of each record.
5. Run this on a schedule.

Comment: This is very helpful I will try this. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds basic but it's simple and it works.  It was the foundation of how automation like this was done at some large companies I've worked for in the past.  The real key is to not do anything which blocks SQL from processing new incoming records.  Get too far into triggers and you can run into some real snags.

Comment: I did everything but I am still having trouble getting a single cell from the CSV as a variable. e.g I want to run a function like...Get-ComputerInfo using the computer name given by the user.

Comment: When you run step 3, do you get a list of all of the unprocessed items from your SQL table?  You would probably be using DBA tools or something similar like mmsSQL to run the query.  https://github.com/fredbainbridge/mmsSQL

Comment: I did get all the values. It isn't a usable format though. With the header and '---------'. How can I get just the single cell. I tried exporting data to a CSV and then get it from there. but it is the same problem. Thank you for your help btw. Its clear I don't know enough so I am watching videos.

Comment: At this point you should either edit your question or ask another sharing the exact command you use to query SQL, and then a snippet of the output you get.